# Git stage and amend with one command

Tags: git, git-amend

Currently I am doing this to amend my changes to the most current commit:
`$ git add .`
`$ git commit --amend`

Is there a way to stage and amend in one command?

Comment: mind explain why the downvote? this was a legit question that bothered me. I tried to do my research before this but could not find out the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Woops, Just found out this would work.
Didn't know `-a` and `--amend` could be used together.
I am putting answer to my own question in case someone wondering the same.
`git commit -a --amend`

Comment: Note that there's a bit of difference between this and `git add .; git commit --amend`. It's the same, on success, as `git add -u; git commit --amend`. (This is often what you want anyway—just be aware that it won't add *new* files.)